# My code isn't shifting the elements to right, want to delete specific elements from array and shift them to right?

Tags: c++

```cpp
 //method to delete specific elements in range and shift to right
    int deleteAll(int start, int end)
        {    
            for(int i = start; i<=end; i++){
                arr[i]=0;
                for(int j = i; j<counter; j++){
                arr[j]=arr[j+1];
                cout<<arr[i];
                }
                counter --;
            }
```

Comment: What is `arr` declared as? Where is `counter` initialized? This is not a [mcve]

Comment: It is strange why you want to shift the elements to the right after a deletion.  What is usually done is to shift the remaining elements after the deleted items to the left.

Comment: declaration of int arr[10];

Comment: counter is iniatilized as private in class I have only uploaded the method

Comment: suppose the array is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

Comment: *I have only uploaded the method* -- A [mcve] means that we can take the code you posted, make *no* changes to it, compile it, run it.  Describing what your code has in it is not enough.

Comment: I want to delete the from index 3 to 5 for example and shift remaining ones to the end as value zero

Comment: okay let me post this again thankyou

Comment: It is still not clear what you are trying to achieve.  OK, so the array starts out as `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`.  What is the end result if you delete index 3 to 5?

Comment: the end result is 1,2,3,0,0,0,7,8,9,10

Comment: i want it to be 1,2,3,7,8,9,10,0,0,0

Comment: Think about it for a moment.  Why are you setting anything to 0 at the start?  Wouldn't you want to set the elements "at the end" to 0?  Forget about the program for a moment, and do this with pencil and paper.  Wouldn't you simply overwrite the position to erase with the numbers to the right, and then at the end, stick 0's at the end of the array?

Answer (score 0):

If you permit, I've got a few moments to mention:

1. We do not need to set `arr[i] = 0` in the beginning of the loop body because we right after it we assign another value (right after, in an inner loop we assign `arr[j]` to `arr[j + 1]` when `j = i`).
2. We can make the algorithm faster if we get rid of the inner loop. How can we do it? Please, see below.

I suppose, this is what you are searching for:

```
int deleteAll (int start, int end)
{    
    int shift = end - start,
        i_lim = counter - shift;
    for(int i = start; i < i_lim; i++)
        arr[i] = arr[i + shift];
    
    // the following loop is necessary only if you want
    // to reset the last elements of the array
    int null_value = 0; // <- you can put anything you like here
    for(i = i_lim; i < counter; j++)
        arr[i] = null_value;
    
    // new length is shorter:
    counter -= shift;
}
```

For better efficiency you can change `int start` to (twice more compact in some C++ implementations) `unsigned short int start`. And same goes for `int end`. Have a good day! =)